# primeng tree table with checkbox not working as expected if a page contains more than one tree table

Tags: angular, primeng

I am working on angular app. I am using tree table

```
   <p-toast></p-toast>

<h5>Checkbox Selection</h5>
<p-treeTable
  [value]="files5"
  [columns]="cols"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="selectedNodes3"
  dataKey="name"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div class="p-d-flex">
      <p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox></p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox>
      <span class="p-ml-2">Toggle All</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{ col.header }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template
    pTemplate="body"
    let-rowNode
    let-rowData="rowData"
    let-columns="columns"
  >
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
        <p-treeTableToggler
          id="{{ i }}"
          [rowNode]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableToggler>
        <p-treeTableCheckbox
          [value]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableCheckbox>
        {{ rowData[col.field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>

............................................................................................................................................................................................................
<p-treeTable
  [value]="files5"
  [columns]="cols"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="selectedNodes3"
  dataKey="name"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div class="p-d-flex">
      <p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox></p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox>
      <span class="p-ml-2">Toggle All</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{ col.header }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template
    pTemplate="body"
    let-rowNode
    let-rowData="rowData"
    let-columns="columns"
  >
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
        <p-treeTableToggler
          id="{{ i }}"
          [rowNode]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableToggler>
        <p-treeTableCheckbox
          [value]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableCheckbox>
        {{ rowData[col.field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

Stackblitz::

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetableselection-demo-py68pi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Code is working fine but the problem is in case if I have two tree table in my html page as shown in stackblitz and above example. If I check first element of first table, than first element of second table automatically gets checked and vice versa. Same for other elements as well. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are binding both tables to the same variables. So both tables show the same info and show the same selections

Comment: yes data coming from api will have same variable name. That's why I am using it. Any way to resolve it?

Comment: You can use the same data, but you cannot save the selection of both tables in the same variable. If both tables are binded to the same variable ( the one that stores the selected nodes ) both will select the same items. Just create a second "selectedNodes" var and assign it in the second table  [(selection)]="secondSelectedNodes3" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tables selection are binded to the same variable `[(selection)]="selectedNodes3"` so once you select a node in one table the other will show the same selection thanks to the angular two-way data binding ( https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding ).

So, in order to fix your issue you just have to use two different variables to store the selection.

First table:

```
p-treeTable
  [value]="files5"
  [columns]="cols"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="selectedNodes3"
  dataKey="name"
>
...
```

Second table:

```
p-treeTable
  [value]="files5"
  [columns]="cols"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="secondTableSelectedNodes3" // <-- This variable must be different from the first table
  dataKey="name"
>
...
```

Then in your component ts you must declare both variables:

```
...
public selectedNodes3: TreeNode[];
public secondTableSelectedNodes3: TreeNode[];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same variable, hence the same reference. Therefore when you update the value both views get updated.
you can use lodash's cloneDeep() to copy the variable without reference then you can use it in your second table.

Comment: yes data coming from api will have same variable name. That's why I am using it. Any way to resolve it?

Comment: If you can provide more detail about what you're trying to achieve with the second table, I might be able to give you a better answer